# What is the value assigned when using MOV instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Can you explain what is the difference between the two usages of MOV instruction?

```
mov eax,[namedDataItem]
mov eax,namedDataItem
```

Here namedDataItem is a named data item defined in .data section.

Comment: You forgot to mention what assembler you use. In some assemblers those two mean the same thing.

Comment: I am using NASM assembler

Comment: [nasm requires brackets](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2).

Comment: https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-effaddr.html

Comment: But by using brackets with named data items can we store the address of that data item to a register? I mean through the first usage in my question

Comment: @Kaustav no, brackets never mean address

Comment: Check the URL in previous comment.

Comment: In NASM the first one moves the contents of the 32-bit DWORD at memory address labelled `namedDataItem` and moves it to _EAX_. The second moves the value (its address) of the label  `namedDataItem` into _EAX_ .

Comment: In NASM, the one with `[]` is a load, the other one is a `mov r32, immediate32`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from 
[NASM Manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2)

> The rule is simply that any access to the contents of a memory
>   location requires square brackets around the address, and any access
>   to the address of a variable doesn't.
>
> This also means that NASM has no need for MASM's OFFSET keyword, since
>   the MASM code `mov ax,offset bar` means exactly the same thing as NASM's
>   `mov ax,bar`.

So, the difference between both lines is : the first one moves the CONTENT, the second moves the ADDRESS.